# MoveAsync to LocalStorage folder UWP

Tags: pdf, local-storage, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to move file from Assets folder of my project to LocalStorage folder. But on the step of moving to LocalStorage I get an "Unauthorized access exception. Access denied". Here is my code:

```
StorageFolder storageLocalFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder storageAssetsFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\Content");

File = await storageAssetsFolder.GetFileAsync("testPdf.pdf");
await File.MoveAsync(StorageLocalFolder, "testPdf.pdf", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

After this line I receive exception. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Please post **real** code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MoveAsync will try and fail to remove the files from the original location.
The InstalledLocation isn't writeable, so you can't remove the files from the Assets folder.  Instead of trying to move them, copy them with StorageFile.[CopyAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync.aspx)

```
await File.CopyAsync(StorageLocalFolder, "testPdf.pdf", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. And what I've found out additionally is that Assets folder is poor for such operations, need to use another place